# How can I create API client library in .NET Core project

Tags: api, .net-core, openapi, swagger-codegen, nswag

We have created a new API project using .NET Core 6 and create some API controllers. For that, how can we create an API client library for this project to consume the API?

Comment: What's the actual question? You already used the tags of the tools used for this. Have you tried something and run into problems? Have you checked the [code generation docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#code-generation) ?

Comment: you want to creat MVC or Angular or React clients? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Answer (score 1):

**If I am Not wrong, You meant to create a API client Library, which we can consume at an Web API project!**

For this, At first Create a class Library project with the required implementation of API client.
Refer - [Creating a .Net Library project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Integration onto Web API Project-

**local setup** - Build the class library and once done, in the Web API -> Add project *dependencies* / references of the class library or add .dll file(You can find this in bin folder).

Resolve dependencies of class Library in Web project if any and consume the api client.

**Advanced** - cloud setup - publish it to artifactory and you can consume it via nugget package